# Can't route to methods in BaseController when Derived is using ODataRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api-odata

I'm having problems routing to my `BaseController` for controllers where I define extra `[ODataRoute]`s.

- GET ~/odata/Foos **WORKS**
- GET ~/odata/Foos(1) **WORKS**
- GET ~/odata/Foos(1)/Bars **WORKS**
- GET ~/odata/Bars **404 Not Found**

**BaseController**

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : ODataController where T : class
{
    protected IGenericRepository<T> Repository;

    public BaseController(IGenericRepository<T> repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() // <---------- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    {
        return Ok(Repository.AsQueryable());
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int key) // WORKS
    {
        var entity = Repository.GetByKey(key);
        return Ok(entity);
    }
}
```

**Controllers**

```
public class FoosController : BaseController<Foo>
{
    public FoosController(IGenericRepository<Foo> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }

    // Can route to base without problems
    // Both base.Get() and base.Get(1) works
}

public class BarsController : BaseController<Bar>
{
    public FoosController(IGenericRepository<Bar> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }

    // Can't route to base.Get()
    // But base.Get(1) works

    // GET /Foos(1)/Bars
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("Foos({key})/Bars")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBars(int key) // WORKS
    {
        var result = Repository.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.FooId == key);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Additionally I tried going the convention way. But that doesn't work either.

```
public class FoosController : BaseController<Foo>
{
    public FoosController(IGenericRepository<Foo> repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }

    // GET /Foos(1)/Bars
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBars(int key) // WORKS
    {
        var result = Repository.AsQueryable().Bars;
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean ~/Foos etc, since that's what's in the code? And why should ~/Foos work if there is no handler for it?

Comment: Yes Foos sorry. There is a handler for it in the BaseController

Comment: Oops, I messed up! I listed the wrong routes as not working. Fixed now - sorry